# Using free with double pointer to a struct

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I am trying to understand how to use `free` function. In the following snippet, I create `ctx` using `malloc`.

```
void serve(ctx **some_struct_type) {
     // .. some operation
}

int main() {

  context_t* ctx = malloc(sizeof(struct context_t));
  serve(&ctx);

}
```

Since each malloc call must have a corresponding `free` call and I want to call free inside `serve`, should it be `free((**ctx))` or `free((*ctx))`?

I am a little confused with the way I must invoke free.

Comment: When in doubt, always check the data type.

Comment: In passing, you're not supposed to use names ending in `_t` for your own types - those are reserved by Standard C - and you can make your allocation more obviously the right size for the variable: `ctx = malloc(sizeof *ctx);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a pointer in main

```
context_t* ctx = malloc(sizeof(struct context_t));
```

To free the allocated memory in main you could write

```
free( ctx );
```

However you passed the pointer by reference to the function `serve`

```
serve(&ctx);
```

So to get the referenced object (pointer) in the function you have to dereference the pointer declared as the function parameter (I will change the function parameter to make sense to the function)

```
oid serve( context_t **p ) {
```

That is you need to write

```
free( *p );
```

where `*p` is the `lvalue` of the original object `ctx`.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, the value of `ctx` is address of a block of allocated memory.  It is this value that gets passed to `free`.

If you pass the address of `ctx` to a function, then you need to dereference that pointer to get the pointer value that you got from `malloc`.

So assuming the function is declared as:

```
void serve(struct context_t **ctx) {
```

You want `free(*ctx)` inside of this function.

Comment: If I would need to do this inside main that will it be just `free(ctx)`?

Answer (score 0):

**malloc** function is used for allocating certain amount of memory during the execution of a program. It sends request to the OS and if it is possible the OS will reserve the requested amount of memory from the heap. *(The function returns address of allocated space)*

```
+-------+------------------+------+----------------------+
| stack | -> free space <- | heap | data & code segments |
+-------+------------------+------+----------------------+
```

**free** works in the other way, it takes the address *(reference)* that points to some memory block and deallocates it.

If you want it to be deallocated in main, you would do it like this:

```
int main() {

  context_t* ctx = malloc(sizeof(struct context_t));
  free(ctx);

}
```

but since you are converting it to double pointer (pointer to pointer) you need to dereference it back to that address you allocated:

```
int main() {

  context_t* ctx = malloc(sizeof(struct context_t));

  ctx **some_struct_type = &ctx;

  free(*some_struct_type);

}
```